# Web App Publishing Error

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5, glimpse

I'm seeing this error immediately after publishing my web app using MVC 5:[image]

I have not found much related to this that isn't from at least 2013 and which references outdated Entity Framework packages. This doesn't seem to apply.

I have updated all installed packages and still have this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look on the [FieldAccessException Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.fieldaccessexception(v=vs.110).aspx).

> The exception that is thrown when there is an invalid attempt to
>   access a private or protected field inside a class.

Also on the remarks:

> This exception is typically thrown when the access level of a field in
>   a class library is changed, and one or more assemblies referencing the
>   library have not been recompiled.
>
> FieldAccessException uses the HRESULT COR_E_FIELDACCESS, which has the
>   value 0x80131507.

Make sure all required libraries are compiled. In some cases (when I publish asp.net websites) I had to do the following steps:

1. Go to the properties of the required file
2. Set BuildAction - `Content`
3. Set Copy to Output Directory - `Do not copy / Copy` (In my case `Do not copy` worked)

Comment: "FieldAccessException" isn't a class in my solution - where do I find it?

Comment: It is an exception class native to the .Net framework. Please check the link I provided or the remarks on my answer. A common problem is sometimes not all files are deployed on the hosting site when you are publishing. You might need to identify the class that wasn't compiled and not included on the publish for some reason.

Comment: Is there a good method for identifying the class that wasn't compiled?

Comment: I uninstalled the Glimpse package - there was no 'BuildAction' option in the properties window for the References -> Glimpse file. This has led to other issues, however. Thanks for your help.